# i am taking data from singelton class to one of the list my activity but in list am getting last value ,please can anyone sort it out for me

Tags: java, android

**Code :**

```
studentName=Singleton.getInstance().getNameId();

 Log.v("studentname",""+studentName);

 Iterator it=studentName.entrySet().iterator();

 while (it.hasNext()){

 Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) it.next();

 String name= String.valueOf(entry.getValue());

 students.setName(name);

 list.add(students);

 Log.v("students",""+list);

  }
```

and the log displaying

```
02-02 11:35:01.140 17483-17483/com.example.tiger.servertest V/students: [Student One]
02-02 11:35:01.140 17483-17483/com.example.tiger.servertest V/students: [Student two, Student two]
```

Comment: Show more part of code where `students,list` is defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Should Create students object each time when you set new name and then adding students reference into list. In your case students hold reference and when you set new name into students object it overrides previously added object in list.

Look below Code I have added one line in your code . try with this.

```
studentName=Singleton.getInstance().getNameId();

Log.v("studentname",""+studentName);

Iterator it=studentName.entrySet().iterator();

while (it.hasNext()) {

    Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) it.next();
    String name= String.valueOf(entry.getValue());
    students = new Students(); // Add this line 
    students.setName(name);

    list.add(students);

    Log.v("students",""+list);
}
```